# SapUI5 Change color / opacity of an editable field

Tags: css, input, background, sapui5

Hello I would like to change the color of my editable fields (make them darker) I tried to use css with a class and back-ground color but it doesn't work, it's like my input doesn't take it in account. Can you help me ? Why my input doesn't take in count the css ? Is their an other way to make my fields darker ?
Thank you

[image]

[image]

Update : the css doesn't work on the input (equipement) and text area field (description)
[image]

Here the code in my view

<f:SimpleForm id="otDetailForm" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanXL="3" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" labelSpanS="12"
adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="4" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1"
singleContainerFullSize="false" backgroundDesign="Solid">

<f:content>

```
                <Label text="{i18n>modifLabelEquip}"/>

                <Input class="background" id="equipmentInput" enabled="{viewModel>/isEditingOt}"
                    value="{path: 'maintenanceOT>EquipementNumber', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.String', constraints : { minLength: 1, maxLength: 15 }}"
                    showSuggestion="true" suggestionRows="{maintenanceOT>/EquipementSet}" suggest="handleSuggestEquipment" showTableSuggestionValueHelp="false">

                    <layoutData class="background">
                        <l:GridData span="XL4 L4 M4 S9"/>
                    </layoutData>

                    <suggestionColumns class="background">

                        <Column class="background" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">

                            <Label  class="background" text="{i18n>creationColumnEquipNumber}"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column  class="background" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
                            <Label  class="background" text="{i18n>creationColumnEquipDesc}"/>
                        </Column>
                    </suggestionColumns>
                    <suggestionRows class="background">
                        <ColumnListItem  class="background">
                            <Label  class="background" text="{maintenanceOT>EquipementNumber}"/>
                            <Label  text="{maintenanceOT>EquipementDescription}"/>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </suggestionRows>
                </Input>
                <Button icon="sap-icon://tree" tooltip="{i18n>detailEquipmentToolTip}" enabled="{viewModel>/isEditingOt}" press="onOpenEquipDialog">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="XL1 L1 M1 S3"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Button>
                <Label text="{i18n>modifLabelEquipArret}"/>
                <CheckBox id="breakDownCheckBox" selected="{path: 'maintenanceOT>BreakDown', formatter: '.formatter.fromStringToBool'}"
                    enabled="{viewModel>/isEditingOt}" select="onCheckboxChange"
                    visible="{path: 'maintenanceOT>OrderType', formatter: '.formatter.isCorrectiveMaintenance'}"/>
                
                <Label text="{i18n>detailLabelUserStatus}"/>
                <Select class="background" id="userStatusSelect" items="{maintenanceOT>/UserStatusSet}" selectedKey="{maintenanceOT>UserStatusLine}"
                    enabled="{viewModel>/isEditingOt}">
                    <core:Item key="{maintenanceOT>Id}" text="{maintenanceOT>Id} - {maintenanceOT>Text}"/>
                </Select>
                <Label text="{i18n>detailLabelPriority}"/>
                <Select class="background" id="prioritySelect" items="{maintenanceOT>/PrioritySet}" selectedKey="{maintenanceOT>Priority}" enabled="{viewModel>/isEditingOt}">
                    <core:Item key="{maintenanceOT>Id}" text="{maintenanceOT>Text}"/>
                </Select>
                <Label text="{i18n>detailLabelActivityType}"/>
                <Select  class="background" id="activityTypeSelect" items="{maintenanceOT>/ActivityTypeSet}" selectedKey="{maintenanceOT>ActivityType}"
                    enabled="{viewModel>/isEditingOt}">
                    <core:Item key="{maintenanceOT>Id}" text="{maintenanceOT>Id} - {maintenanceOT>Text}"/>
                </Select>
                <Label text="{i18n>detailLabelDescription}"/>
                <TextArea class="background" rows="5" value="{maintenanceOT>OrderOpeDescription}" enabled="false"/>
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle with the code?

Comment: It is working for Select but not for Input? Then maybe your selector is wrong or not specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine with class="full-opacity" in the input and the text area and to change the background i change the opacity of the class like that in my css :

`.full-opacity { opacity: 1 !important; }`